# Characterization of totally-split primes in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$

Tags: algorithms, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$.
If it makes it easier, feel free to restrict to $n = p^k$, or $n = 2^k$ even.
I want to find the factorization of any totally-split prime $p$ (smaller is better generically, but not of utmost importance) .
It's well-known that:
\begin{equation}
p\text{ is totally split in }O_K\iff p\equiv 1 \mod n
\end{equation}
With this in mind, looking at the arithmetic sequence $\{n+1, 2n+1,\dots\}$, and appealing to Dirchlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions is enough to find some $p$, and then I can factor it directly.

My issue is that this seems "wasteful" in a certain sense --- to find some *small* objects (the individual factors $p_i$), I have to find some *large* object, and factor it.
Without getting into too many specifics, it's insufficient for my purposes.
Is there any known way to find the $\mathfrak{p}_i$ factors (that are totally split) "directly"?
By this, I mean without appealing to factorization of some large prime, or more specifically in poly-time (in $k$, when $n = p^k$)? Alternatively is there any known method for *any* number field that's poly-log in the degree?

One thought is that the galois group of $K$ acts transitively on prime decompositions, so it's enough to find a single $\mathfrak{p}_i$.
Moreover, we should be able to identify when $\mathfrak{p}_i$ is totally split by checking if it's ramified (via $N(\mathfrak{p}_i)$ and $K$'s known discriminant) and checking that the inertial degree is 1.
This suggests some strategy of enumerating small ideals, applying the above checks, and hoping we find one soon.
While I don't know precisely how efficient this is, I have strong doubts that it's efficient enough for my purposes.

Is there any known method for finding a *single* factor in a totally-split prime in a number field efficiently?

Comment: The prime ideal is $(p,\zeta_n-m)$ with $p \equiv 1 \bmod n$ and $m \bmod p$ of order $n$. If you don't want to generate $p$ before finding a corresponding $m \bmod p$, you can generate $m$ then find a corresponding $p$, that is you want an integer $m$ such that $m^n-1$ has more prime factors than $\prod_{q | n} (m^{n/q}-1))$. Is there any 3rd way ?

Comment: @reuns Is there any simple way to see why $m$ has order $n$ mod $p$ specifically?

Moreover, would you then say that trying to do this in poly-log (in the degree) time is unfeasible? Looking at the prime factors of $m^n - 1$ seems pretty unlikely to be fast enough